# Tip for developing mobile ste

Tags: mobile, user-interface, responsive-design

I am creating a mobile site and working on WAP for the first time and my main concern is that the site should render properly possibly on all handsets.

So,I was thinking to adapt responsive design approach.
But then I came across this sites :

http://www.webdesignshock.com/responsive-design-problems/
http://dapurpixel.com/blog/articles/responsive-web-design-pros-and-cons/

So,please provide some best practices to follow while developing mobile site. I googled it but it showed my tutorial for responsive design and I am not sure that this is the optimum method.

Thanks

Comment: I use this: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/22/device-agnostic-approach-to-responsive-web-design/.  I also use SMACSS methodology.

Comment: hey thanks a lot, I will definitely look into it.But I want one more suggestion, right now existing development team detects the handset via PHP and gets its width n then the width is stored in CSS variable and rest of the elements gets css property wrt the wrapper div defined.So, is this approach better ? hope you got what I am trying to convey.

Comment: That's an interesting approach.  The DARL methodology bases the layout on range of device widths.  So in one range you would target phones and the fluid layout would stretch or contract to the devices viewport.  Then have a range for tablets, desktop, etc.  Coding for specific pixel widths is a losing battle, there are just too many devices entering the market with varying viewport sizes.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the website you are creating. Some type of websites (such as blogs) are really easy to make as responsive design. But some other websites (e-commerce, news magazine, deep websites) should be adapted specifically for mobile and tablets. Why? Because making the website adapts its width and column layout is often not enough.

Also keep in mind some features such as mouseover is rather complicated for tablet users. So menus with click that opens an accordion menu is simpler and feels more right. Creating a design that would work for everyone (One design to rule them all) could take more time to implement than simply creating a specific version of your website for handheld devices.

So it all depends on the nature of your website.